# Is nodes(path) ordering guaranteed to always be the same?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my graph each node has a name and graph is actually a tree, so there exists a `/path/to/each/node`. Here's the query I currently use to get the path:

```
MATCH p=(n:Node{id:4})-[:CHILD_OF*0..200]->(r:Root{treeName:"vt"})
RETURN reduce(path = "", node IN nodes(p) | node.name + "/" + path) as path
```

An actual query is somewhat heavier, but the behavior is the same. So, having a `("")<-("a")<-("b")<-("c")<-("d")` path I will get `/a/b/c/d/`. I don't mind trimming the last `/`, but I'm really worried about the order of the nodes iterator returned by `nodes(p)`.

So, my question is mainly targeting neo4j team - are there any guarantees as to the order? Would it be better is I just returned `Path` and then manually extracted each property? I'm using Cypher with an embedded neo4j distribution, so that won't be a problem.

Comment: My expectation is that `nodes` iterates in order through the path, returning `n` as first node and `r` as last one. If you observe different behaviour I'd consider this being a bug.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster, yes, you are right, I'm able to get them in any order I like by varying patterns (i.e. (p)->(n) vs. (n)<-(p)), but since I could'n find any documented guarantee, I thought it might be worth to clarify the matter.

Comment: The direction of the relationship won't influence the order of nodes. The `nodes()` ordering should reflect the nodes in the same order as you specify them in your path specification.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster, well, it does: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=4otd3r

Comment: @StefanArmbruster, ah, I see. I think we both meant the same.

Comment: If you want direction to affect order you can do `RETURN reduce (path='',r IN relationships (p) | endNode (r).name + '/' + path) + n.name AS path`. Assuming, of course, that `relationships` maintains the order in the path :-) It does leave out the trailing `'/'`, as would reducing on `nodes(p)[1..]` and concatenating the first (last) node name afterwards.